# Java recursive iteration through hashmap returns values multiple times

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap

I have a Java Hashmap which contains Strings as key and a list of complex elements as value for each key.
I want to find all possible combinations of values, if exactly one value must be chosen for each key.
The following code gives me all possible combinations. Unfortunately, some combinations are returned more than once.

For the key /value combinations

W – w1, w2

X – x1, x2

Y – y1, y2

Z – z1,z2

The code returns:
w1

w1, x1

w1, x1, y1

w1, x1, y1, z1

w1, x1, y1, z2

w1, x1, y2, z2

w1, x1, y2, z1

w1, x1, y2, z2 (already found before)

Any hints how I can avoid getting combinations more than once?

```
private HashMap<String, ZeugnisNoteMitAa> result;



public DeutschCheck(final String bezeichner, final List<String> schulartenList) {
        super(bezeichner, schulartenList);
        mloesungGefunden =false;
        mbeste = new HashMap<>();
        result = new HashMap<>();
        mbearbeitet = new HashMap<>();

    }
private void loesungGefunden(HashMap<String, ZeugnisNoteMitAa>map)
    {
        for (Map.Entry e : map.entrySet())
        {
            ZeugnisNoteMitAa note = (ZeugnisNoteMitAa) e.getValue();
            System.out.println(e.getKey()+" "+ note.getZeugnisNote().getSchuleFach().getUnterrichtsfach().getAnzeigeform()+" "
                    + note.getZeugnisNote().getNote()+ "\n");
        }
    }

private void doit(HashMap < String, List < ZeugnisNoteMitAa >> map, List < String > keys, int currentKey, int currentValue) {
  if (currentKey >= keys.size()) {
    return;
  } else {
    List < ZeugnisNoteMitAa > currentValues = map.get(keys.get(currentKey));
    if (currentValue < currentValues.size()) {
      result.put(keys.get(currentKey), currentValues.get(currentValue));
      boolean found = true;
      for (String current: keys) {
        if (result.get(current) == null) {
          found = false;
        }
      }
      if (found) {
        //Print the current selection
        loesungGefunden(result);
      }

      doit(map, keys, currentKey + 1, 0);
      doit(map, keys, currentKey, currentValue + 1);

    }
  }
}

public class ZeugnisNoteMitAa {

    private final ZeugnisNote mZeugnisNote;
    private final SchuelerFachwahlFachAa mAa;
    
    public ZeugnisNoteMitAa(final ZeugnisNote zn, final SchuelerFachwahlFachAa aa) {
        mZeugnisNote = zn;
        mAa = aa;
    }
    
    public ZeugnisNote getZeugnisNote() {
        return mZeugnisNote;
    }
    
    public SchuelerFachwahlFachAa getAa() {
        return mAa;
    }
    
    public SchuelerOberstufe getSchuelerOberstufe() {
        return mAa.getSchuelerFachwahlFach().getSchuelerFachwahl().getSchuelerOberstufe();
    }
```

I tried to find out how the machine steps through the Hashmap (noted above). I can’t find out, how to do the recursive method call that each combination only occurs once.

Comment: Hello and Welcome! Please, you English in the code you're exposing. And the code you've posted is incomplete (for instance, where `result` comes from?). Can you provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Result is a global variable which is empty when the method is called. The method is called with a list of all keys: doit((HashMap<String, List<ZeugnisNoteMitAa>>) e.getValue(), keyList, 0, 0);

Comment: I guess you mean an *instance* variable or maybe even a class variable, since there are no global variables in Java.  Leaving aside the fact that using such a variable for the apparent purpose is terrible form, we need to know the *type* of that variable to understand the behavior of your method.  And if `loesugGefunden()` modifies its argument or any instance or class state then we need to know about that, too.

Comment: private HashMap<String, ZeugnisNoteMitAa> result;                        
 private void loesungGefunden(HashMap<String, ZeugnisNoteMitAa>map)
    {
        for (Map.Entry e : map.entrySet())
        {
            ZeugnisNoteMitAa note = (ZeugnisNoteMitAa) e.getValue();
            System.out.println(e.getKey()+" "+ note.getZeugnisNote().getSchuleFach().getUnterrichtsfach().getAnzeigeform()+" "
                    + note.getZeugnisNote().getNote()+ "\n");
        }
    }

Comment: Please, use the *edit* button or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74280095/edit) to update the question. **Don't** post the code, or other clarifications that are crucial to the problem in the comments - update the question (and then you can use comments to notify users that have commented the question earlier that it has been updated).

Comment: Added method loesunggefunden, member variable result and constructor

Comment: Can you share ZeugnisNoteMitAa ?

Comment: Shared ZeugnisNoteMitAa. For copyright reasons I can't share classes used inside this class.

Comment: I wrote an example to see if this is what you want to achieve: https://shrib.com/#Frederick6zMddZY 
Let me know if I understand it well.

Comment: Not exactly, there must be one x and one y in each solution. The difficulty is that x1 y1 is the same as y1 x1 and should only appear once